# how can i evaluate generic type in runtime in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

i need to evaluate generic type at runtime using `Type.GetType()`

```
Type t  = Type.GetType("className");
Table<t> table = dataContext.GetTable<t>();
```

any ideas please ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, normally you need to get the generic method (e.g. with `Type.GetMethod`), then call `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`, then invoke it.

However, is there any reason you don't just want to call [`DataContext.GetTable(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310460.aspx)?

You won't be able to *use* the table generically anyway... so is `ITable` (the return type of `GetTable(type)`) good enough for you?

Comment: thnx jon, so how can query ITable 
is that possible ??

Comment: @mahmoud: Yes - it extends `IQueryable`. But it won't be terribly *easy* to query it if you don't know the type. If you could explain more about what you're trying to do, that would help.

Comment: i have n number of identical Tables in DB (identical in structure) , will be mapped to n class in DataModel

i want to create a generic solution to work with all of them 

is that possible ?

thnx in advance

Comment: @mahmoud: I'm not sure, to be honest. It's *possible* that you could create an interface that all of them implement... but I don't know enough about LINQ to SQL to say for sure.